# Add SDK tools to path in Android Studio app

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I have just installed Android Studio 0.2.2. I want to add the SDK tools to the `$PATH`, which are in this folder:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools
```

so that I can use them with e.g. Phonegap.

But after I add this folder to the `$PATH`, it still keeps saying:

> android: command not found

Oddly, I can't run any of the executables in that folder even when I `cd` to that folder and type their names.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 61):

It seems that newer versions of Android Studio don't come bundled with the SDK. So, `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools` will no longer work.

After launching the SDK Manager from Android Studio, I realized the new path is 
`/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools`.

#### Steps

1. Open your `~/.bash_profile` file by issuing the command `open ~/.bash_profile` on the terminal
2. Add the following lines to the end of that file

   1. `export PATH=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH`
   2. `export PATH=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:$PATH`
   3. `export PATH=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`
3. Save and close the `~/.bash_profile` file
4. If you want the changes to take action on the current terminal, then `source ~/.bash_profile`; otherwise, close and re-open the terminal, and the changes will take place automatically

Answer (score 10):

You can add this folder to you PATH in `.bash_profile` (a hidden file in the home folder of the user):

```
export PATH=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools:$PATH
```

and then reopen the terminal application.

If you need an environment for all your UI apps, you can use the `.launchd.conf` (or `/etc/launchd.conf` for all the users).

Comment: i have already added it to path, my problem is that it still says command not found.

Comment: /Users/keune/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/keune/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/Users/keune/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/keune/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Comment: Very strange. It works form me. You are trying to execute "android" command from bash, right?

Comment: Exporting the path in .bash_profile affect only the bash terminal for the user. If you want to set an environment for all the UI apps, you may to edit .launchd.conf.

Comment: +1 for telling the .launchd.conf thing. Never knew how to add paths to non-terminal stuff in OS X (never ever needed it, either!)

Comment: anyone who can't get it to work yet then try writing ./adb instead of adb . It works. Like in this case it didn't work for me and then i added ./ infront and it works. voila

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
# Add the Android SDK tools to $PATH and set $ANDROID_HOME (standard)
ANDROID_HOME="${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk"
if [ -d "${ANDROID_HOME}" ]; then
  PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools"
  PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_DIR="${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools"
  PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_DIR}/$(ls -1 ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_DIR} | sort -rn | head -1)"
fi
```

The build tools are unlike the others in that they're in subfolders. Eg there's `build-tools/23.0.3`, `build-tools/25.0.1`, `build-tools/25.0.2`... so this chooses the most recent one.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting bit by the escape character.

The reason tiziano's answer works for him is because the export command needs that backslash after "Android"

however, you are probably editing /etc/paths. When you put the path in there, you don't need the backslash, just put the lines:

/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools

in /etc/paths, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
~/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk
```

Comment: I am using Mac OSX 10.10.3 and Android Studio 1.2.2