# Finding Android SDK on Mac and adding to PATH

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have installed Android Studio on my MacBook Air (OS Version 10.11 El Capitan) and have successfully written a small "hello, world" app and installed on device (Nexus 7) and ran on AVD.  All I want to do now is be able to build the app and install it on device from the command line as opposed to Android Studio.  I'm following the directions here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

and the relevant line is:

Make sure the Android SDK platform-tools/ directory is included in your PATH environment variable, then execute:

The problem is I can't find the Android SDK on my machine!  I assume it's there because otherwise the program wouldn't compile and run through Android Studio?  Perhaps that's a bad assumption?  I'm new to Macs (I'm used to Windows) so I don't know the best way to search for the Android SDK.  So my questions:

1. How do I find Android SDK on my machine? Or prove to myself it's not there?
2. If it's not there how do I install it?
3. How do I change PATH to include Android SDK?

Comment: try searching here `/Library/Android/sdk/`

Comment: you need to export 2 paths -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143183/add-sdk-tools-to-path-in-android-studio-app

Comment: you can find the path in your sdk manager: Android Studio->Preferences->Appeareance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK-> here Android SDK Location

Comment: Try `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 537, accepted):

### 1. How to find it

- Open Android studio, go to **Android Studio > Preferences**
- Search for `sdk`
- Something similar to this (this is a Windows box as you can see) will show [image]

You can see the location there – most of the time it is:

```
/Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk
```

### 2. How to install it, if not there

- Go to [Android standalone SDK download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
- Download the zip file for macOS
- Extract it to a directory

[image: Standalone SDK download page]

### 3. How to add it to the path

Open your Terminal edit your `~/.bash_profile` file in nano by typing:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

If you use Zsh, edit `~/.zshrc` instead.

Go to the end of the file and add the directory path to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/tools:${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

- Save it by pressing `Ctrl+X`
- Restart the Terminal
- To see if it is working or not, type in the name of any file or binary which are inside the directories that you've added (e.g. `adb`) and verify it is opened/executed

Comment: Thanks. I followed step 1 and saw the path was:  /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk   Curiously, using "Finder" and Go->Go To Folder, I couldn't get to it by drilling down from /Users/user/Library etc.  The user directory did not show Library!  Must be some strange Mac thing.  I had to put the full path in Finder.

Comment: For posterity, this link might be useful for adding to PATH:  http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/    I had to manually type the path in for the export.  Nowhere in "Finder" did I see a copy directory name like in Windows.  Sigh...

Comment: Restart the Terminal after you safed the /etc/paths file

Comment: Recommend not edit `/etc/path` directly. use "export" in ~/.bash_profile instead.
Ex. `export PATH="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/":$PATH`
after add above to ~/.bash_profile just use `source ~/.bash_profile` if there is no error you can freely to use `adb` command

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly for me. I had tried to export in ~/.back_profile but that did not work at all.

Comment: Nice post! To me, these are all things that could happen automatically when installing the sdk though... 

Comment: Thanks, only difference I had is, I had to use `open .zprofile`, and update the exports  there since it is M1 chip (zsh)

Answer (score 58):

If you don't want to open Android Studio just to modify your path...

## They live here with a default installation:

```
${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/tools
${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

## Here's what you want to add to your `.bashwhatever`

```
export PATH="${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/tools:${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

Comment: it works for mac user, must try, thank you :)

Answer (score 21):

#### Find the Android SDK location

```
Android Studio 
  > Preferences
  > Appearance & Behaviour
  > System Settings 
  > Android SDK
  > Android SDK Location
```

#### Create a `.bash_profile` file for your environment variables

- Open the Terminal app
- Go to your home directory via `cd ~`
- Create the file with `touch .bash_profile`

#### Add the PATH variable to your `.bash_profile`

- Open the file via `open .bash_profile`
- Add `export PATH=$PATH:` `[your SDK location]` `/platform-tools` to the file and hit `⌘s` to save it. By default it's:

  `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/yourUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`
- Go back to your Terminal App and load the variable with `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 13):

> 1. How do I find Android SDK on my machine? Or prove to myself it's not there?

When you install Android studio, it allows you to choose if you want to download SDK or not

> 2. If it's not there how do I install it?

you can get SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

> 3. How do I change PATH to include Android SDK?

in Android Studio click in File >> Settings [image]

Answer (score 9):

If Android Studio shows you the path `/Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk` 
but you can not find it in your folder, just right-click and select "Show View Option". There you will be able to select "Show Library Folder"; select it and you can access the SDK.

Answer (score 6):

The default path of Android SDK is `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk`, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402196/6521116).

add this to your .bash_profile to add the environment variable

```
export PATH="/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:${PATH}"
```

Then save the file.

load it

```
source ./.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 5):

I found it here:
/Users//Library/Android/sdk

and Platform-tools is available as well

[image]

Comment: /Users/L... and not /Users//. ?

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidStudioFrontScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsryT.png)I simply double clicked the Android dmg install file that I saved on the hard drive and when the initial screen came up I dragged the icon for Android Studio into the Applications folder, now I know where it is!!! Also when you run it, be sure to right click the Android Studio while on the Dock and select "Options" -> "Keep on Dock".
Everything else works.
Dr. Roger Webster

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual Studio for Mac** users (e.g. who installed Android SDK together with VS):

- open Visual Studio for Mac
- select from menu: Tools -> SDK Manager -> Select 3rd tab: 'Localizations' in dialog

You can find JDK, Android NDK and Android SDK localizations there (if installed and selected). If no Android SDK path found, you may try to find it using Android Studio (if it is installed)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to create local.properties file with sdk.dir=PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK in my machine. It seems that, it's regarding the android sdk path setup. Hence, it could also be set in ANDROID_HOME env. variable too.