# Android studio having issues with android sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I have installed Android studio 3.3.2 on Mac. By mistaken I have deleted sdk folder located on Library/Android/sdk . Now I have uninstalled android studio and installed it again but now its not downloads android sdk again and pointed to old path and later it giving me error like Nothing to do!
Android SDK is up to date.
SDK tools directory is missing

Please help me out how to resolved this issue .

Thanks in advance !![image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqeAR.png)

Comment: Check this answer to completely uninstall Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/3024933

Comment: I have already done this but no luck , still having same issue

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing/42508937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto `settings>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK` and download the required sdk

Answer (score 2):

Go to @ *your directory* and create the **SDK** folder manually. This will fix the stated problem.

> C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Update : [download SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)

Comment: But how to download sdk content

Comment: I have manually created directory and copy platform tools downloaded from mentioned link but still having same issue

Comment: Ok so first go to configure afterwards click on sdk manager take that sdk path copy it and go to configure --> project defaults-->project structure and add it into the android sdk location path there you go. @Pone

Comment: Your answer is working only on Windows, but in the question, the user has Mac.

Comment: @Pone catch up with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532063/finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path