# Mac Big Sur version 11.0.1 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation'

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter

I'm getting IDE Fatal Errors.

I'm working on a Mac Big Sur version 11.0.1
Android Studio 4.1.1
Developing a Flutter

I found this link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244962
New in macOS Big Sur 11 beta, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache.

I have no idee how to solve these fatal Errors in
Kind regard,
Robert

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation':
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:302)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:455)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:570)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getMacFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:363)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getDateTimeFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.<clinit>(DateFormatUtil.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.status.StatusPanel$5.run(StatusPanel.java:196)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:232)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:367)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:184)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:847)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:496)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 42 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 42 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:276)
        ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading my Android Studio to version 4.2 Beta 2 on my mac solved the problem.
Thank you for your inputs!

Kind regards,
Robert

Comment: Hmmm I have AS 4.1.2 (not a beta) problem still there. On MacOS 11.1

Comment: Error message has disappeared now. Big Sur 11.2.2 and Android Studio 4.1.2

Comment: The same with Big Sur 11.2.3 and AS 4.0.2

Answer (score 5):

New in macOS Big Sur 11 beta, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache. (62986286)

(explanation copied from
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2808)

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way to get around this error would be to revert to an earlier version where you were not getting this error. Right click on the project folder and navigate to local history to revert to an earlier version. I verified this work around on an android studio installed on Mac OS Big sur. This solution would also resolve the dlopen issue, app stopping issue and app restarting issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Configuration error

flutter config --android-sdk < path where android sdk installed >

Comment: In case you wonder where to get android sdk path, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532235/12718080

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with the other answers, but eventually what worked for me is:

Upgrading my project in 'File -> Project Structure' to the latest stable SDK.

On the JetBrains forums, this issue has been resolved, and this error you're getting even with the latest stable MacOS version should be solved, if you're using the latest stable versions of the SDK.

Answer (score -2):

Have you Spring in your project? Maybe problem showing themself when app is setting up the ApplicationContext; Try to run tests (if you has its) and looking for bugs in stacktrace;
In my case I have the problem with this dependencies:

```
<groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
<artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
```

I had a old version 4.2.x; I had changed this to 4.9.5 and this helped me.
Maybe you should to change version of some dependencies.

Comment: Upgrading the Android Studio to version 4.2 Beta 2 delivered the fix for me