# React Native Flipper Debugging Issue : "NO APPLICATION SELECTED"

Tags: android, react-native, flipper

[image]

I have managed to connect a device ( I see logs and see the tree of React Native elements), but now I have an issue with connecting the app - "NO APPLICATION SELECTED" is what I see. Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ran into the same problem on both iOS and Android with Flipper 0.135.0. Managed to make both work by following the steps below.

#### iOS

[This answer](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/3432#issuecomment-1046760632) solved the issue for me.

tl;dr

```sh
brew update && brew upgrade idb-companion
```

Also make sure you are installing the correct Cocoapod of Flipper by specifying the exact version in your Podfile with (for version 0.135.0)

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper'=> '0.135.0' })
```

---

#### Android

Ensure that *ReactNativeFlipper.java* is in the correct folder, as in  [this example project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f627f684bb6506a677c9632b2710e4a541690a9/template/android/app/src/debug/java/com/helloworld/ReactNativeFlipper.java).

With for example the applicationId *`com.domain.appName`*, the correct path is

*android/app/src/debug/java/com/domain/appName/ReactNativeFlipper.java*

In my project this Java file was in the incorrect folder, which resulted in the Logcat error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.domain.appName.ReactNativeFlipper

Comment: Where can I find an application id?

Comment: @Olek You can find your application id e.g. in the _app/build.gradle_ file. [Application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id)

Comment: You could still try to move that java file into the correct folder. But there might of course be something completely else that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! Found an issue: my application id name was structured like ```domain.developerName.appName```, I just had to move ```ReactNativeFlipper.java``` to ```android/app/src/debug/java/com/domain/developerName/appName/ReactNativeFlipper.java```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The error message says it is looking for the java class com.domain.ReactNativeFlipper even though my Application ID is io.domain. I tried moving .../debug/java/com/domain to .../debug/java/io/domain. Also tried .../debug/java/com/io/domain as per @AlexUA solution. But it always shows an error looking for com.domain.ReactNativeFlipper. Guess NiFi is right, something else is wrong.

Comment: For iOS:

```brew tap facebook/fb && brew install idb-companion```

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Go to settings and check if the path for your Sdk is correct

Comment: To find your SDK path, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532063/finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that you are running the latest version of Flipper (0.120.0 as of this message) and then:

For Android:

- Bump the `FLIPPER_VERSION` variable in `android/gradle.properties`, for example: `FLIPPER_VERSION=0.120.0`.
- Run `./gradlew clean` in the android directory.

For iOS:

- Call `use_flipper` with a specific version in `ios/Podfile`, for example: `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.120.0' })`.
- Run pod install in the ios directory.

Reference: https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/#using-the-latest-flipper-sdk

Comment: That's what I did, but for some reason, situation hasn't changed

Comment: What version of react native and flipper and flipper kit are you using? @Olek

Comment: personally, i am using rn 0.66.3 with flipper 0.122.0 @micnguyen

Answer (score 2):

In my case issue was with the Emulator OS and API.

I used following combination and it worked:

- **Device:** Pixel 4a
- **OS:** Android 12
- **API:** (Release Name: S, API level: 31, ABI: arm64-v8a, Target: Android 12

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, I was not seeing android simulator and the app to select, but it was working fine for iOS without any config.

The problem with my setup was that in the Flipper settings, the android SDK's path was not correct, after updating the path and restarting Flipper, it automatically detected the simulator and the app.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve that on Android, open `ReactNativeFlipper.java` file

In the first line `package com.yourappname;` change it to exactly your package name inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In the MainApplication.java there is a line like

```
 initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
```

inside onCreate() function. In my project this line was commented. I removed the comment and run react-native run-android and  flipper get connected to the app

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

1. Set the path to Android SDK correctly
2. Ensure the watchman is set up
3. Ensure the Setup Doctor is not flagging any issue

None of the above resolved the issue until I uninstall the app from the device, close the Metro Bundler terminal, and then run `yarn android` after this Fipper "NO APPLICATION SELECTED" error disappeared.

***Desktop FLIPPER_VERSION=0.201.0
React native Android FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0***

Answer (score 0):

for macos, check if /usr/local/bin/idb-companion exist
if brew link to another path, create link to it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).