# How do i add android tools to my path on mac?

Tags: android, terminal, path

I'm trying to add get the android development environment to work om my mac. I'm following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

I'm supposed to add the sdk to my path using:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

however this does not give me acces to the 'android' command in the termial and when I execute $ANDROID_HOME i keep getting:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/android-sdk-macosx
```

I've checked the path in

> Android Studio>Preferences>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK

SDK location should be correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you replace myname with your mac osx user name ?

Comment: yes I did, I just left it out when i posted it here

Comment: try dragging the Android folder into terminal window to find its actual path

Comment: If i drag it to terminal it sais: /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Comment: then use that sdk path in the above commands

Comment: I've tried both  "export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/android-sdk-macosx" and "export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Android/android-sdk-macosx" and neither work

Comment: whats the content inside the `android-sdk-macosx` ? its looking for a adb path i think

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I just set up a Mac mini for work using the following steps, so I can guarantee this works with a fresh install.

1) Install Android Studio. (Standard is fine, Custom if you want to)

2) Launch Android Studio

3) From the Welcome Screen, click Configure (bottom right corner) > SDK Manager

4) Double check that you have the latest platform tools and tools installed in the SDK Tools tab.

At this point, you will have installed everything related to the android sdk, including the tools, in the default location of `/Users/your-user-name/Library/Android/sdk`

5) Create a .bash_profile file if you don't already have one at `/Users/your-user-name`

6) Add the following lines to it: (replace my username with yours)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chris.w.newman/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chris.w.newman/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/chris.w.newman/Library/Android/sdk
```

By adding it to your .bash_profile, these lines will run every time you use a shell. So you don't have to worry about them ever again.

To test that everything works correctly, try the following 'which' commands from a new shell:

```
which adb
which android
```

Since these are added to the path, you should see their file path printed in the shell.

Comment: This is a good explanation, though I kept having to do it on every power on, so I used [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x) by Ashish (5th one down) on creating a .bash_profile and used the 3 statements from #6 and it has worked great.

Comment: Please note that you will need to go for another bash configuration file in case if you are using `zsh`. More details https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3807

Comment: A little bit smaller would be:
`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`

Comment: @Harry For version 3.+ must remove the **/sdk** in the ANDROID_HOME export

Answer (score 4):

So after checking out this post: [Add sdk tools to path in Android Studio app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143183/add-sdk-tools-to-path-in-android-studio-app)

I tried:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools:$PATH
```

and it worked

Comment: Works only with version 2.+, path are modified in 3+ (see @Harry comment)